# How to position vote count underneath vote button?

Tags: html, css, button, text

I am a beginner trying to create a music artist voting page. I am confused about positioning the vote count text underneath the vote button. If there is also anything else I can improve in my code please let me know.

I've tried different floats and displays but I'm not really sure what I am doing.

```css
p {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.bart {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

button {
  list-style: none;
}

td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<img class="bart" src="bart.gif">
<div class="artist-list">
  <ul class="artist">
    <table>

      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="coleclick()"><li>J.Cole</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="cole">0</a></p>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="slipknotclick()"><li>Slipknot</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="slipknot">0</a></p>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="amineclick()"><li>Amine</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="amine">0</a></p>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="daveClick()"><li>Dave</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="dave">0</p></td>
      </ul>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by playing with the `flex-direction` attribute.

```
td {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Just keep in mind that when you do this, `justify-content` and `align-items` will change the axis they affect. No problem in this case if you use `center` for both.

```css
p {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.bart {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

button {
  list-style: none;
}

td {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<img class="bart" src="bart.gif">
<div class="artist-list">
  <ul class="artist">
    <table>

      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="coleclick()"><li>J.Cole</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="cole">0</a></p>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="slipknotclick()"><li>Slipknot</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="slipknot">0</a></p>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="amineclick()"><li>Amine</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="amine">0</a></p>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #ffc854; border: none;" onClick="daveClick()"><li>Dave</li></button>
        <p>Votes: <a id="dave">0</p></td>
      </ul>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gerrardo, this help is greatly appreciated! Is there anything else in my code that could be improved?

Comment: @RDA28 ur welcome. I would really recommend not using `table` for layout, try to look into css grid or just plain fun flexboxes. I really appreciate if u can approve and upvote. Code on!

Comment: check this out for flex box. its an amazing tool https://www.steveaolsen.com/docs/FlexboxCheatsheet.pdf

Comment: @sao that's a great cheatsheet, this is also a nice game to practice flex-boxes https://codepip.com/games/flexbox-froggy/